# multi curl with http and https

Tags: php, curl, https

I'm trying to use multi curl, but I'm not sure if the problem I'm having is because one link is regular http, and another link is https.

I used `curlsetopt($ch[$i],CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false)`

But I get an error message, if I make this to true, I don't get any errors, but I'm not getting any data from the https link. would this be the problem?

Error : `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Thanks

```
$urls = array(
  "http",
  "https"
   );

$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
       $conn[$i]=curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//return data as string 
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);//follow redirects
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,2);//maximum redirects
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);//timeout
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
       curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

       curl_multi_add_handle ($mh,$conn[$i]);
}

do { $n=curl_multi_exec($mh,$active); } while ($active);

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
       $res[$i]=curl_multi_getcontent($conn[$i]);
       curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$conn[$i]);
       curl_close($conn[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);


print_r($res);
```

Comment: could you show your full code for cURL

Comment: @Sudhir hi, I supplied my full cURL code. Thanks!

Comment: On which line does the error occur? I have a hunch that it's occurring on the final line of the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From playing more with this code. It does seem to work,

What does not work is `print_r($res[0]);`